# creating textbox when button click in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i already searched few stackoverflow threads related thisbut i have problem in code plz review my code and tell me where is the problem i am stuck and do not where is the problem i am new here please  help me out

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
    Grid MainGrid = new Grid();
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();
        dynamicTextBox.Text = "Type Partnumber";
        Grid.SetRow(dynamicTextBox, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(dynamicTextBox, 0);
        this.MainGrid.Children.Add(dynamicTextBox);
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem u r facing ?

Comment: when i click it does not creat

Comment: your `MainGrid` is not added to the `Window` yet.

Comment: your MainGrid is not a set to Window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `button_Click` event you are adding the dynamic TextBox to the `MainGrid` and that code looks fine. But the problem is that `this.MainGrid` is not in the Present UI, its similar to the dynamically created TextBox, since you ware defined it in the code-behind(see the definition above the constructor `Grid MainGrid = new Grid();`).

Consider that `canContainer` is a canvas defined in the xaml as like the following,

```
<Canvas Height="319" Margin="0"
        Width="517"
        Name="canContainer"/>
```

To overcome this you can choose any of the following method.

1.Add The `MainGrid` to the UI. it will add the grid to the canvas, keep in mind the dynamic textBox already added to the Grid.
which means the code should be like this -->

```
 this.canContainer.Children.Add(MainGrid);
```

2.Add `dynamicTextBox` to any other parent which is present in the UI.

```
this.canContainer.Children.Add(dynamicTextBox);
```

You you are using this method then need not to define and adding `MainGrid`

Comment: should i add dynamic textbox to xml

Comment: @Marina : no need not like that, wait let me add sample code

Comment: how we can set text box value to combo box